# Can we say "He is accountable but not blamable" ? Do "accountable", "responsible", "answerable" imply "blamable"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

I know "accountable", "responsible" and "answerable" are used in the following way in English,

> The engineering team is accountable for this failure of the system.
>
> The terrorists are responsible for this attack to the train station.
>
> He is answerable for the accident.

But I have a confusion that I'm not sure if those words imply that people who are responsible are one of the causes of the problems and deserve punishment, i.e., blameable ? I am confused because in my mother language (Chinese) we distinguish two cases,

> The first case is, someone held the duty of doing a job and he did it as best as he could. Unfortunately something bad happened which was impossible to be stopped (e.g. blackout of the whole city and backup power didn't work for no reason). In this case, the investigators of the problem think he was in charge of the job and **should give his explanation (be accountable ?)** to the problem to help identify the cause. If the investigators determined, after necessary examinations and questions, that the problem was indeed caused by something impossible to stop, then we think he **should not be blamed**. It is a tragedy but no one should be blamed.
>
> The other case is that it is for sure that someone did something bad accidentally or on purpose to cause the problem, then he is blamable.

So my question is whether the words "accountable", "responsible" and "answerable" can tell the difference between the two cases ? If not, how can we use English to distinguish the difference ?

Can we say "He is accountable for this accident but not blamable", or "He was **involved in the accident but not accountable/responsible/answerable for it**" ?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between *accountable* and *responsible*, or about the difference between *accountable* and *blamable*, or whether *accountable* sometimes also means *blamable* and sometimes not?

Comment: @NickGammon I thought "responsible", "accountable" and "answerable" have the same meaning, in that someone who is "responsible" should be blamed. The answer by TRomano tells me that I am wrong with the meaning of these words. I also want to know whether there are words which can express the case where someone is involved in the problem but should not be blamed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are **responsible for** something that happened, they did it or allowed it to happen.

If they are **accountable**, they are the ones who must justify or defend their decisions and actions, or their failing to act.  There may or may not be punishment, depending upon how well the accountable acquit themselves.

If they are **answerable**, they will have to answer for it, and usually this implies suffering punishment or retribution.

Comment: Er, I can understand your answer, but I guess it is a bit conflict to the [dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accountable). The dictionary says "accountable" and "answerable" have a meaning of "responsible" ...

Comment: Don't you mean to say "a" dictionary? And you're not reading those definitions very carefully.

Comment: I mean the "[accountable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accountable)" term in the Merriam-Webster dictionary gives a meaning of "responsible", though I think your answer is reasonable.

Comment: That's not what the definition says. It mentions the word "responsible", true.

Comment: Er, this is an example given by the dictionary, " 2
:  responsible 1 <You're accountable for your mistakes.>". I think it means "You are not only required to explain the mistake but also blamable. Do you think so ?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "blamable".

Comment: By blamable I mean as you said he did something wrong so that the problem happened, and then he deserved the punishment.

Comment: "*Something wrong" is an extremely vague and encompassing expression, and not everything that falls into that broad category is punishable or deserving of punishment. What do you have in mind? A misdemeanor? A felony?  A breach of personal trust? A breach of public trust? An infidelity?  A sin? Eating the last cookie? A war-crime?

Comment: You also have to pay attention to the preposition used with the verb:  **answerable for** and **answerable to** mean very different things.

Comment: Thanks very much for your clarification. I think I can understand it partially if not all.

Comment: Why not provide examples taken from Google news? [**Accountable for**](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=nws&q=%22accountable+for%22) and [**responsible for**](https://www.google.co.uk/#tbm=nws&q=%22responsible+for%22)

Comment: _"If they are responsible for something that happened, they did it or allowed it to happen."_ I disagree. You can be ultimately responsible for something merely by being in a figurehead position of authority over those who were, even though in practice you had no control over the goings-on whatsoever.

Comment: Lightness: Not quite precise enough in your expression of the idea. That person might be **held** responsible, but they are not **responsible for** something over which they have no control whatsoever.

Comment: Hm, i've seen "responsible for" explained as "obligated to respond to" rather than "caused" a few times…

Comment: @StarWeaver: The overwhelming majority of the time, when we say that "he was responsible for the hotel fire", we mean that he started it or failed to take actions to prevent it, not that he had to answer questions about it, although the responsible party may be held accountable.

Comment: I think the problem is that "blameable" is a moral/legal assessment of culpability and there is often room for debate. There is no doubt that the captain of a ship is responsible, accountable, and answerable for its safety; there can be considerable doubt about whether he or she carries any blame when it capsizes in an extreme storm.